# Ngx-Translate doesn't get translations after page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm working on Angular 13 app, and I have a problem with ngx-translate.
The problem is that, when I'm navigating through the project, translations which I'm getting using TranslateService are working properly, but every time I refresh the page, translations which I'm getting using TranslateService are not being translated.
Here's my the template(example) of my code:

```
getKeywords() {
this._translate.get([
  "keywords.keyword1",
  "keywords.keyword2",
  "keywords.keyword3",
]).subscribe(result => {
  this.keyword1Translation = result["keywords.keyword1"];
  this.keyword2Translation = result["keywords.keyword2"];
  this.keyword3Translation = result["keywords.keyword3"];
});
```

}

'_translate' refers to TranslateService which I'm getting as a dependency in the class constructor of the component.
I've tried calling getKeywords() method that I've created in class constructor and I also tried calling it in ngOnInit, but the result is the same. When I'm navigating through the project, translations are displayed properly, but when I refresh the current page, I'm getting, for example, 'keywords.keyword1' displayed.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

1. app.module.ts

   ```
   export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
     return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
   }

   export class TranslateHandler implements MissingTranslationHandler {
     handle(params: MissingTranslationHandlerParams) {
       /* some logic */
     }
   }

   export function appInitializerFactory(translateService: TranslateService, injector: Injector): () => Promise<any> {
     // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
     return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
       const locationInitialized = injector.get(LOCATION_INITIALIZED, Promise.resolve(null));
       locationInitialized.then(() => {
         translateService.use(localStorage.getItem("language") || window.navigator.language) // here u can change language loaded before reander enything
           .pipe(take(1))
           .subscribe(() => {},
           err => console.error(err), () => resolve(null));
       });
     });
   }

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           ...,
           TranslateModule.forRoot({
               loader: {
                   provide: TranslateLoader,
                   useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
                   deps: [HttpClient]
               },
               isolate: false,
               missingTranslationHandler: [{provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: TranslateHandler}]
           }),
       ]
       providers: [
           ...,
           {
               provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
               useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
               deps: [TranslateService, Injector],
               multi: true
           }
       ]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```
2. in module of your component add `TranslationModule`
3. in component constructor `public ts: TranslateService) {}`
4. now u can use:

   ```
   this.ts.instant('YOUR_KEY'); // return translated string or your key if translation not founded, but u can change logic in TranslateHandler
   ```
5. all translations stored in **assets/i18n/**. for example **en.json**